# Xcode NsCoding navigation title disappears

Tags: xcode, crash, title, nscoding, initwithcoder

I have added this code to the "MasterViewController.m" in my project:

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
[encoder encodeObject:_savedText forKey:@"savedText"];
}
```

.

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
if((self = [super init])) {
    _savedText = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"savedText"];
}
return self;
}
```

When I added the "initWithCoder-code" the navigation title disappears and when I click the "add button" in the navigation bar the app crashes.
(_savedText" is a mutableArray) What causes the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't call `[super init]`. Call `[super initWithCoder:]` instead.